# LinkedIn shares api to retrieve likes and comments

Tags: linkedin-api, linkedin-jsapi

I have created an app on linkedin's developer platform which is trying to get the likes and comments on the posts that users share. I am using V2 shares API for that. OAuth flow has been done successfully but when I am trying to get the scope **r_member_social** , my app is not allowed for that.
After a bit of reading I concluded that I need to have linkedin partnership. From the available products on the app page I requested for **Marketing Developer Platform** but have not given access. So I have following questions:

1. Is there any other api to retrieve the comments and likes on the posts done by the user apart from using shares and social api's?
2. What is the procedure for adding **r_member_social** scope to the application?